# Will my macbook start downgrading my performance at 67 degrees celcius?

Tags: temperature

My MacBook Pro has been suddenly behaving suspiciously slow -- the temperature censors hover around 67 degrees Celsius.

Does the kernel task (or another mechanism) start throttling performance at these temperatures?

Thanks!

Comment: While kernel_task is designed to help temperature by denying CPU hogs, 67 sounds low, unless kernel_task is the highest CPU user compared to everything else. In that case kernel_task is working as intended. Sounds like you have an IO bottleneck, or lots of swapping on top of slow IO. You'll need to give a bit more detail about what tasks are running when you experience this, also Intel or Apple Silicon, what OS version?

Comment: Precise model will help (particularly if Intel CPU) so that we can lookup CPU limits for you on Intel web site.

Comment: For further context, my M1 MBP is currently running face detection in my preferred DAM and regularly tops 90-100C with the app using 300% + CPU, without breaking a sweat thanks to the whisper quiet fans (a vast improvement on my old Intel MBA from 2012, which would take off under the same load...) kernel_task is not having to throttle the system or do anything remedial and the laptop is still perfectly usable. Ofc Apple Silicon manages CPU allocation differently with a split of performance & efficiency cores.

Comment: I'd agree that the temperature is probably not the cause: that's a low temp for CPUs.